# PHP code coverage - Understanding path coverage

Tags: php, phpunit, php-code-coverage

I just started working on a piece of software using PHP 7.4.27 with PHPUnit 9.5.7 and Xdebug 2.9.8. I am collection code coverage including branch and path coverage information for all my unit tests. In class "Content" I have a method named "unwrap" for which I am not able to interpret the results of the path coverage data.

This is the method in question:

```
public function unwrap(string $elementToUnwrap = null): self
{
    if (empty($elementToUnwrap)) {
        $this->content = $this->unwrapData();

        return $this;
    }

    $value = $this->get($elementToUnwrap);

    if (!is_array($value) && !is_object($value)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('The element to unwrap must exist and it must be of type array or object.');
    }

    $this->content = $value;

    return $this;
}
```

And these are the path coverage results for "unwrap":
[image]
Can anybody please tell me

1. the difference between the two yellow marked paths
2. the difference between the two blue marked paths

I do not understand why sometimes a line is repeated three times (`if (!is_array($value) && !is_object($value)) {`) and sometimes only two times?

Comment: I think there is a bug somewhere in the xdebug code coverage collection of data. The lines should not be repeated in the code coverage analysis.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sounds like a logical explanation.

Comment: I just dont understand why. Did you maybe make changes to the file while xdebug was collecting data for code coverage?

Comment: No, I did not. Xdebug seems to think that there are 5 paths but I don't understand why.